# ¡Hola! Tengo un problema con el módulo discord y discord.ext. ¿Qué tengo mal?

Tags: python

Recientemente desinstalé Discord porque quería usar nextcord. Todo salió mal con nextcord y cuando intenté instalarlo de nuevo, me marca un error, que no puedo importar comandos de discord.ext. Aquí está mi código:

Módulos

```py
import discord
import urllib
import random
from discord.ext import commands
```

Y el error es:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)
```

Si necesitas algo solo pregúntamelo por favor, ¡gracias!

Comment: Esto es [es.so]. El idioma oficial es el castellano. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Listo, traducido

Comment: Está todo bien? Necesita otro cambio?

Comment: Esperar que los especialistas de Python te pidan algo. Pero podrías añadir el mensaje de error que dices recibir al tratar de instalar la dependencia.

Comment: Debes importarlo de esta forma `from nextcord.ext import commands`. Puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/intro.html) para guiarte